# Angular $resource Get An Object with Number Keys

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm using `$resource` to get a JSON object. Now it returned an object with number keys which was expected to be a JSON.

### My code:

```
$resource('url', {
        'param': 1
    }
});

var data = Session.get(function(e) {});
```

m {0: "[", 1: "{", 2: "s", 3: "h", 4: "o", 5: "p", 6: "I", 7: "d"

Hope to be a string like this:

```
'[{"shopId":"1","shopName":"name"}]'
```

[image]

Network console seems right.
[image]

It's worked well with jQuery.

### jQuery code:

```
 $.ajax({
         url: requestUrl,
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
             'param': 7
         }
 })
```

Comment: i m sorry what is the question ?

Comment: The question is that now i got a wrong data, maybe it's because of format. but i don't konw how to fix it.

Comment: what does jQuery return? If expecting array need to make sure isArray is set for that method

Comment: Added in question. JQuery return a string. I can parse this string to JSON.

Comment: Can you parse returned object to json using JSON.parse() and see if its ok ?

Comment: It is an object. So there is an error when using JSON.parse. Added in Question is a picture of this situation.

Comment: Look at your browser's *Network* console. What is the **exact** response from the server?

Comment: Added Network console picture in the question.

Comment: Why is your server responding with a quoted JSON string? The response should simply be `[{"shopId": ...`

Comment: Just because of 'Quoted'?

Comment: As Phil mentioned the JSON response of the server is not valid because of the `'`.  `Error: Parse error on line 1: '[{"shopId":"1","sho
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`. You can always use a JSON validator to check your validity - https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Comment: I got it. It is just as Phil said.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comment.

Phil is right.

Why is your server responding with a quoted JSON string? The response should simply be [{"shopId": ...